# List View set command Extension sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I am new to SharePoint extesions and I have to work upon List View Set Command extensions I have to create a dialog box in which I have to add three field People Picker, Textfield and cancel save button can anyone help me to do this Please.

I tried to creating dialog box but it was not woking

Answer (score 0):

You can start over with reading documentation on SharePoint List View Command extension, and watching the introductory video over here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api